# Break very large records in a table into smaller records

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2016 on Azure - let's say we have a table with 4 columns: `ID` (Primary Key/Identity), `Source`, `Url`, `Text`.  This table has approximately 20 million records. Approximately 20% of these records contain a `Text` field with data that is greater than 10MB.  We want to, on a daily basis, scan the table and break up any record with a `Text` field greater than 10MB into smaller records, each with a maximum of 10MB in size.  So for example, if a record has a `Text` field that is 28MB in size, it would get broken into 3 records - 2 each of 10MB and one of 8MB.  The resulting records would have incrementing `ID` values (as is the default on table inserts), and the `Source` and `URL` fields would be identical across the 3 records.

How would one begin to approach this?  Can this be achieved by writing a query as a Stored Procedure and setting it to run on a schedule, or is something that should be written as an application?

EDIT 1: per user's question below, it's valuable to add why we need to do this: The reason for doing this is that we push our data through an extractor process to parse the text and extract relevant information. The largest amount of data the extractor can take in a given call is 10MB.

Comment: *The resulting records would have incrementing ID values (as is the default on table inserts)* As I remember - no guarantee. In `insert into table (val) values (1),(2),(3)` the guarantee is that `id` for `1` will be less than for `2`, but I have never seen somewhere that adjacent values will be produced...

Comment: In any case you can:insert into the table the chunks of a record text, then delete source record, performing this record-by-record in a cursor.

Comment: Assuming an auto incrementing ID field, your adjacency will be fine. Important question, though: What version of SQL Server are you using?  If it is SQL 2005 or later, my first step would be to convert the Text field to a Varchar(MAX) field.

Comment: @LaughingVergil *Assuming an auto incrementing ID field, your adjacency will be fine.* Is it documented somewhere for concurrent inserts?

Comment: I'm not certain that he is necessarily talking about concurrent inserts. Using a table valued function as a source would only require an identity field on the output table to ensure sequence, and if doing it in a loop in inline code, sequence would be preserver by the state of the code.  Unless used in multiple locations, the table-valued function would be redundant, since it would require two INSERT sequences - one for the TVFs internal table, one for the target table. So it is reasonable to assume that sequence is preserved, and it can be easily ensured.

Comment: @LaughingVergil the Text is already nvarchar(max) type. SQL Server version is the  first sentence of the post.

Comment: @Akina I think we may want to avoid cursor approach: the last time we had a cursor-based procedure run daily on this table, it took up to 10 hours per day to complete.  I was told that the cursor approach is inefficient.

Comment: *it took up to 10 hours per day to complete* O_O how many records with length(txt)>10M will be inserted DAILY? Anycase you can chunk this operation (for example not more than 100 records per chunk) with the period not enough to insert 100 records in average.

Comment: You could also use a trigger to automate the process on Insert or Update of the Text field.

Comment: @LaughingVergil ... and then use phamtom update for to divide existing records. Excellent!

Comment: LaughingVergil and Akina great suggestions so far, thank you both very much.  Can you suggest a simple syntax for the Trigger?  I am rather green to this and would appreciate assistance with a starting point...

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose for doing this is. If it is to separate the LOB data from the other data, then that support is already available by configuring the "large value types out of row" option for sp_tableoption. Additionally you can also specify that the data LOB data for a table go a different filegroup using TEXT_IMAGE ON in the CREATE TABLE/INDEX command.

Comment: This just smells like Future You is going to be sorry it was done this way.  Please have a candid chat with Future You before continuing with this particular solution.

Comment: @TonyHinkle LOL.  Well I'm not sure what way you're referring to since I haven't mentioned a particular approach that I've decided on.  Please do share which way doing it would make Future Me sorry.  I definitely would not want to go down that road.  Thanks.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi sure that's a great question.  The reason for doing this is that we push our data through an extractor process to parse the text and extract relevant information.  The largest amount of data the extractor can take in a given call is 10MB.  i will add this to original post.

Comment: Why not just change the data type on the field to limit the amount of data inserted and make the corresponding changes in the application? What you're proposing will just cost you more money if you're paying by the minute or CPU clock or whatever.

Comment: @Alen great suggestion for going forward but we need to address existing records before we could reduce the data type size.

Comment: too lazy to code something, but you could probably count up the characters until you get to 10MB. I think it was 1 byte per character. or estimate. Forgot the function, but grab everything past that number of characters, delete and copy into new row. maybe use LEN or RIGHT functions to get the data past a certain number of characters in the field

Comment: @Alen thanks - I'm certainly not asking anyone to write the code for me, just a suggested starting point is very helpful.  I appreciate your input.  Thanks.